# How can make Codable of type PhotosPickerItem?

Tags: swiftui, codable, nscoding, photo-gallery, userdefaults

I'm trying to save an array like PhotosPickerItem (instead of an array of images to save memory) in any available form, for example, through UserDefaults using Codable. However, I can't match the specified type with the Codable protocol, or convert PhotosPickerItem to Data. Also, when I try to use NSObject, NSCoding protocols, an encoding error is displayed when running the code. I would be grateful for advice and code example, as I did not find a suitable option (there are only examples with the String and Int type).

```
// example of Code

import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct PickerItem: Codable {
    var selectedPickerItem: PhotosPickerItem  // **this is not correct (only simple type like String or Int is correct)**

struct PickerItemManager {
    
    static let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    private init(){}
    
    // save Data method
    static func savePickerItems(pickerItem: [PickerItem]) {
        do {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            let pickerItems = try encoder.encode(pickerItem)
            defaults.setValue(pickerItems, forKey: "pickerKeyName")
        } catch let error {
            print(#function, error)
        }
    }
    
    //retrieve data method
    static func getPickerItems() -> [PickerItem]{
        
        guard let pickerItemsData = defaults.object(forKey: "pickerKeyName") as? Data else {return []}
        do{
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let pickerItems = try decoder.decode([PickerItem].self, from: pickerItemsData)
            return pickerItems
        } catch let error {
            return([])
        }
    }
}
```